# Re-Running the function in case "if" condition fails or else continue

Tags: python, if-statement, null, boto3, amazon-sqs

I am trying to get the sum of all the messages available in my multiple SQS queues using boto3. It is executing fine but sometimes only a few of the queues are returning data instead of all of them and the program is returning empty sets. How do I solve this problem using the "IF" condition so that the function re-runs if one of the sets is empty?
PS: I am a newbie to programmming
import boto3
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

```
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
asg = boto3.client('autoscaling')

response = sqs.list_queues(QueueNamePrefix ='Queue')
queuelist = response["QueueUrls"]

soa = 0.0
noi = 0.0
ABPI = 100

def SumOfAverages(queuelist, soa, response, cloudwatch):
    for eachqueue in queuelist:
        step0 = eachqueue.split('/')
        step1 = step0[4]
        response1 = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace='AWS/SQS',
        MetricName='ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible',
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'QueueName',
                'Value': step1
            },
        ],
        StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1),
        EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
        Period=60,
        Statistics=[
            'Average',
        ],
        
        Unit='Count'
        )
        datapoints = response1['Datapoints']
        print(datapoints)
        #*Need If Condition*
        for values in datapoints:
            averages = values['Average']
            soa += averages
    return(soa)

result = SumOfAverages(queuelist, soa, response, cloudwatch)
print(result)
```

Comment: Which function, `SumOfAverages`?  Which set is empty?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that on a "reasonably small" number of re-runs sets will be non-empty? If so, you can write a `while` loop on the condition that sets are non-empty, within the function itself. This will of course fail if in some cases sets keep returning empty, in which case you may want to add a counter, and break out raising an exception if after `n` tries sets are still empty

Comment: You are looking the for-try-except-else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following,

**Approach 1**:

```
max_tries = 3
for _ in range(max_tries):
    response1 = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace='AWS/SQS',
        MetricName='ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible',
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'QueueName',
                'Value': step1
            },
        ],
        StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1),
        EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
        Period=60,
        Statistics=[
            'Average',
        ],
        
        Unit='Count'
    )
    if response1['Datapoints']:
        break
else:
    raise RuntimeError

datapoints = response1['Datapoints']
```

The else block gets executed only if the loop exits without `break` call.

**Approach 2**:

Basically the same idea as above, but put that code in a dedicated function, which you can then add [decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) on to re-try `n` times.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the approach. I used a combination of if-else condition and time.sleep(). Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I use this algorithm

```
#try 5 times?
for attempt in xrange(5):
    try:
        #do_your_stuff()
        result = SumOfAverages(queuelist, soa, response, cloudwatch)
        print(result)

    except Exception as e:
        #manage exception if you need
        print("*except* %s" %e)
    else:
        #If do_your_stuff() run and ends correctly then break for loop
        break
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the approach. I used a combination of if-else condition and time.sleep(). Now it is working fine.